# Blazor Webassembly client fails to load pushNotifications.js in referenced project

Tags: javascript, push-notification, http-status-code-404, blazor, webassembly

I'm attempting to implement push notifications in a reminder app I'm building. I am attempting to follow along to the way it is done in [this demo project](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/master/docs/09-progressive-web-app.md#displaying-notifications). To that end, I added a razor class library project entitled BlazorReminders.ComponentsLibrary to my BlazorReminders solution. Just as the BlazingPizza project did, I put the localStorage.js and pushNotifications.js files under the wwwroot folder of the ComponentsLibrary project. I then added a reference to the ComponentsLibrary in the client project and attempted to load the resources in the client's index.html file as follows:

```
<script src="_content/BlazorReminders.ComponentsLibrary/localStorage.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorReminders.ComponentsLibrary/pushNotifications.js"></script>
```

This is the exact way they did it in the demo project, however for me it returned a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()".

A more detailed console message
GET https://localhost:44304/_content/BlazorReminders.ComponentsLibrary/pushNotifications.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

I've also tried changing the src path to variations of "..\BlazorReminders\BlazorReminders.ComponentsLibrary\wwwroot\pushNotifications.js" to no avail; I got the same errors.

What could be causing the 404? Thanks

**EDIT: Resolved**

Thanks to agua from Mars for pointing out that I had forgotten to update the these package references in my ComponentsLibrary project file

```
//Version had to be changed to 3.2 preview 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" Version="3.2.0-preview2.20160.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="3.2.0-preview2.20160.5" />
```

Comment: Do you use the 3.2 preview ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using.

Comment: Can post your your BlazorReminders.ComponentsLibrary,csproj ?

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the Client project. You are correct, I had overlooked updating the packages in the ComponentsLibrary project to 3.2 preview. Thanks!